# MVC Ajax Begin Form onSuccess data object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

i am using Ajax.Begin Form. onSucces from the controller, i am calling a onSucess(data).

The data is a rendered partial view, I need to get the value of one html field. That field is a json string.

Is there a way i can specify with jQuery to search the data object for the value of a specific field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the data into a jQuery selector like so, $(data), you can then search it just like any other selector with .find(), or use it as a sub selector, $('selector', $(data)).